# Possible to have differing session state modes for various applications under a website?

Tags: session, iis, session-state

I'd like to have the application at example.com use In Proc. And all other applications (example.com/app1, example.com/other_app, etc) use SQL state. Is this possible? I have created distinct application pools for each application.

Comment: This is configured for each application in web.config so what's the problem?

Comment: @KonradKokosa In my parent application I'm saving an object into the In Proc session. But ever since changing the child apps to use SQL sessions, that object gets lost.

Comment: @KonradKokosa hm seems like the web.configs were somehow inheriting from each other. I added a <location> element to the parent and child web.configs and that seems to have helped.

Answer (score 1):

I added a `<location>` element to all of my web.configs:

```
<location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false" allowOverride="false">
    <system.web>
        <sessionState />
    </system.web>
</location>
```

This seems to keep everything separate now. I can now use "In Proc" in my parent app and "SQL session" in child apps and not lose any session data. (A complex object was lost in the parent app because (I think) it was somehow inheriting the session state from children web.configs.)

Answer (score 0):

Should just work with multiple applications. This setting is per application.

Haven't you tried this?

Comment: Of course I tried it. In my parent application I'm saving an object into the In Proc session but ever since changing the child apps to use SQL sessions, that object gets lost.

Comment: (child) apps can't access the session info of other apps, what is you exact setup?

Comment: example.com uses In Proc session state mode. example.com/app uses sql session state mode. example.com/app works great - no issues. example.com loses session data - particularly an object with attributes. It started happening when I changed the child app (example.com/app) to use SQL session state mode.

Comment: seems like the web.configs were somehow inheriting from each other. I added a <location> element to the parent and child web.configs and that seems to have helped.